# Add parentheses to list elements - Python

Tags: python, string, list, file

I would like to retrieve a set of data in a file in the form of a list.

The following is the data i am reading from the file which I want to add to list:

> ## file input: (3,5),(5,2),(2,1),(4,2),(4,1),(3,1)

The following code shows what I have now:

```
with open("partial.txt") as f:
List = f.read().splitlines()

graph1 = ','.join('({0})'.format(w) for w in List)

print (graph1)
```

The output I get is:

```
>> (3,5),(5,2),(2,1),(4,2),(4,1),(3,1)
```

BUT I want the above result in [ ], like this:

```
>> [(3,5),(5,2),(2,1),(4,2),(4,1),(3,1)]
```

Can someone show what I need to do to get the above result

Comment: Do you want to obtain a list of tuples?

Comment: just: `result = [eval(graph1)]`

Comment: yes a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3):

```
import ast

s = "(3,5),(5,2),(2,1),(4,2),(4,1),(3,1)"

>>> list(ast.literal_eval(s))
[(3, 5), (5, 2), (2, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Here is an [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) to `eval` vs `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: I did this and I get: [((3, 5), (5, 2), (2, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1), (3, 1))]. Why is there extra ( ) ?

Comment: Better to use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). The output for this string is the same, but `ast.literal_eval()` won't actually hand out the keys to the process to any comer the way `eval()` does.

Comment: @user3624406: sounds like you did `[eval(s)]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by this code, list of tuples! :

```
with open('partial.txt') as f:
graph = [tuple(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in f]

print (graph)
```